# Trying to return an object from a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

Apologize, but was not able to find an answer for this question. I am finding items on a html and pushing it to an object, but I can't figure out for the life of me, why this function does not return the object? I am able to console without an issue.

```js
function getItem(obj){
  var itemsObj;
  $('.info').on('click', function(){
    itemsObj = {};
    $this = $(this);
    itemsObj.gameImg = $this.parent().parent().find('img').attr('src');
    itemsObj.gameTitle  = $this.parent().parent().find('p').text();
    itemsObj.gameInfo = $this.parent().parent().find('h2').text();
    // console.log(itemsObj);
    return itemsObj;
  });
}
//getItem();
console.log(getItem());
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-3 game">
              <div class="view view-first">
               <img src="img/deathstranding.jpg"/>
               <div class="mask">
               <h2>Death Stranding</h2>
               <p>Death Stranding is an upcoming action video game developed by Kojima Productions and published by Sony Interactive Entertainment for PlayStation 4. It is the first game by game director Hideo Kojima and his company following the 2015 disbandment of Kojima Productions as a subsidiary of Konami and subsequent reformation as an independent studio.</p>
                   i<a href="#" class="info">♥</a>
               </div>
             </div>
```

Comment: Your outer function has no return statement.

Comment: Also itemsObj will be populated only after a user clicks a .info element, not when you call getItem function

Comment: Trying to return a value from an event handler doesn't make sense. Where should it return to? It is *not you* who calls the event handler, it's the browser whenever the event happens.

Comment: I want to push that object to localStorage eventually. and make it available in another page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it is not returning anything it is because you returned the data for `click` event listener function not for `getItem()` function, also there is no way to return it that way

```
function getItem(obj){
  var itemsObj;
  $('.info').on('click', function(){
    itemsObj = {};
    $this = $(this);
    itemsObj.gameImg = $this.parent().parent().find('img').attr('src');
    itemsObj.gameTitle  = $this.parent().parent().find('p').text();
    itemsObj.gameInfo = $this.parent().parent().find('h2').text();
    // This sends data to click event listener not getItem()
    return itemsObj;
  });
}
```

In order to receive the item you wanted you should implement a callback

```
function getItem(callback){
  var itemsObj;
  $('.info').on('click', function(){
    itemsObj = {};
    $this = $(this);
    itemsObj.gameImg = $this.parent().parent().find('img').attr('src');
    itemsObj.gameTitle  = $this.parent().parent().find('p').text();
    itemsObj.gameInfo = $this.parent().parent().find('h2').text();
    // call the callback function parameter and send itemsObj as argument, callback function then received the argument as you wanted it to be. Then execute stuff from there.
    callback(itemsObj);
  });
}

// send a function instead for getItem to call when all is well
getItem(function (data) {
   // here you will receive the data
   console.log(data);
   // stuff
});
```

TIP: If you want a way cooler solution where you want to implement a `success` and `fail` scenarios check [jQuery Deffered](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.deferred/) [JavaScript Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

hope that helps

Comment: Thanks for the help Masterpreenz. will take a look on your solution and the links you provided.

Answer (score 1):

because you are returning from an event handler which is another function itself.
also if you want only push it to local storage , why not do it in the event handler ?

```js
$('.info').on('click', function(){
  itemsObj = {};
  $this = $(this);
  itemsObj.gameImg =  $this.parent().parent().find('img').attr('src');
  itemsObj.gameTitle = $this.parent().parent().find('h2').text();
  itemsObj.gameInfo = $this.parent().parent().find('p').text();
  // getting previous info
  var savedInfo = localStorage.getItem("gamesinfo");
  // since everything is saved as string , we need to use json
  savedInfo = JSON.parse(savedInfo);
  // check if its not null
  savedInfo = savedInfo ? savedInfo : {};
  // use a unique identifier to save objects , do not push the object into an array every time
  savedInfo[itemsObj.gameTitle] = itemsObj;
  // stringify data and save it
  localStorage.setItem("gamesinfo", JSON.stringify(savedInfo));
  
  
  
  // to retrieve all of games info:
  console.log(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("gamesinfo")));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-lg-3 game">
  <div class="view view-first">
   <img src="img/deathstranding.jpg"/>
   <div class="mask">
   <h2>Death Stranding</h2>
   <p>Death Stranding is an upcoming .....</p>
       i<a href="#" class="info">♥</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate answer Javad. but still does not answer my question, I want this all in a function, and if I am able to console log the object and see the properties, how come when I return the function it gives me undefined?

Comment: if you look more carefully , you have defined another function for .on click , and you are returning for that function only , so your getItem function , doesn't return anything , and thats why you are getting undefined . you should check for nearest function definition when you are returning , and in your case , its onclick function you have defined, not getItem. hope it helps.